# jQuery Custom Radio Buttons not working as radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am using JQuery and custom images for custom radio buttons. Right now, it would work as a checkbox. I need it to work as a radio.

When I click on either of both radio's both will get ticked instead of one at a time. Am I missing something?

HTML:

```html
<label for="radio1">
    <img src="radio_unchecked.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
    <input name="radiogroup" type="radio" id="radio1" style="display:none;">
</label>

<label for="radio2">
    <img src="radio_unchecked.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
    <input name="radiogroup" type="radio" id="radio2" style="display:none;">
</label>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#radio1").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).prev().attr("src", "radio_checked.png");
        } else {
            $(this).prev().attr("src", "radio_unchecked.png");
        }
    });


    $("#radio2").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).prev().attr("src", "radio_checked.png");
        } else {
            $(this).prev().attr("src", "radio_unchecked.png");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You have no click handling for the images, I wonder how you can even test any function when the radio buttons are hidden via `display:none;`? The change event never fires, does it? \\edit: Oh, I see, the labels are triggering the radio buttons of course.

Comment: @Connum: The `img`s are within the `label` for the radio button, so the click reaches the label, which is just like the click reaching the radio button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radio buttons are working correctly ([proof](http://jsbin.com/ekavin)), but your logic for updating the images is incorrect. *Both* images have to change when either radio button is clicked, since both values change (and the `change` handler is only fired on the one that you clicked). Have a single `change` handler used by both radio buttons, and set both images on every change, e.g.:

```
$('#radio1, #radio2').change(function() {
  var r;

  r = $("#radio1");
  r.prev().attr("src", r[0].checked ? checkedImage : uncheckedImage);
  r = $("#radio2");
  r.prev().attr("src", r[0].checked ? checkedImage : uncheckedImage);

});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ekavin/3)

---

Side note: If your target browsers support the [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked) (IE only has this as of IE9, not in IE8 or earlier) and [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) from CSS3, you can do this entirely with CSS:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radio1" style="display: none">
<label for="radio1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radio2" style="display: none">
<label for="radio2"></label>
```

CSS:

```
#radio1 + label, #radio2 + label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(radio_unchecked.png);
    width: 32px;  /* Whatever matches the images */
    height: 32px; /* Whatever matches the images */
}
#radio1:checked + label, #radio2:checked + label {
    background-image: url(radio_checked.png);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/avoluk)

Or alternately (it's just the selectors that are different):

```
input[name="radiogroup"] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(radio_unchecked.png);
    width: 32px;  /* Whatever matches the images */
    height: 32px; /* Whatever matches the images */
}
input[name="radiogroup"]:checked + label {
    background-image: url(radio_checked.png);
}
```

Comment: @PPvG: Thanks! Yeah, it works in just about all modern browsers, though sadly not in IE8, which means using it "in the wild" is still a little ways off. Hopefully soon, though!

Answer (score 3):

The `change` event fires only for the radio button that was changed by the user, not for any other radio buttons that may be automatically unchecked in that process.

You should update all of the images when the change event for any radio button fires:

```
var radios = $('input:radio');

radios.change(function() {
    radios.filter(':checked').prev().attr("src", "radio_checked.png");
    radios.filter(':not(:checked)').prev().attr("src", "radio_unchecked.png");
});
```

This will work for **any number** of radio buttons. A reference to the original collection of radio inputs is kept in `radios` (this is more efficient). When any of the `<label>`s is clicked, the event handler fires. Inside the handler, [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is used to separate the `radios` collection into checked and the unchecked radio inputs.

**Working demo: http://jsbin.com/ibaqid/2/edit#javascript,live**

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<label for="radio1">
    <img src="radio_unchecked.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
    <input name="radiogroup" type="radio" id="radio1" style="display:none;">
</label>

<label for="radio2">
    <img src="radio_unchecked.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
    <input name="radiogroup" type="radio" id="radio2" style="display:none;">
</label>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("input[name=radiogroup]").change(function() {
        $("input[name=radiogroup]").prev().attr("src", "radio_unchecked.png");
        $(this).prev().attr("src", "radio_checked.png");
     });
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing:

```
this.checked
```

with this:

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Comment: No, the `checked` property of the raw DOM element for the `input` is completely reliable cross-browser.

Comment: Changed it to this: if $(this).is(':checked') { and it's stopped working ... also tried without the "if" without success