# JQuery Custom Radio Buttons code (code not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery

usual but I need to have different custom radio button images per button.

So Radio1 would have different images to Radio2.

Trying it out on the code below but it won't work so I must be doing something wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<label for="radio1">
    <img src="radio1_unchecked.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
    <input name="radiogroup" type="radio" id="radio1" style="display:none;">
</label>

<label for="radio2">
    <img src="radio2_unchecked.png" style="vertical-align:middle" />
    <input name="radiogroup" type="radio" id="radio2" style="display:none;">
</label>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

var radio1checkedImage = "radio1_checked.png",
    radio1uncheckedImage = "radio1_unchecked.png",
    radio2checkedImage = "radio2_checked.png",
    radio2uncheckedImage = "radio2_unchecked.png";

   $('img').attr("src", radio1uncheckedImage);

$('#radio1, #radio2').change(function() {
  var r;

  r = $("#radio1");
  r.prev().attr("src", r[0].checked ? radio1checkedImage : radio1uncheckedImage);

  r = $("#radio2");
  r.prev().attr("src", r[0].checked ? radio2checkedImage : radio2uncheckedImage);

});


});

</script>
```

Update: [Here](http://jsbin.com/ekavin) is the same code as above but without the multiple images.
As you can see it works. Can't the code be modified to have multiple images per radio?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is it using the same image for both buttons? It's probably because of the line `$('img').attr("src", radio1uncheckedImage);`. That assigns the same image to both radio button images.

Comment: You are binding the change event on the radio buttons but they **are hidden**, makes no sense.

Comment: @Didier: sure it does. Radio inputs can be selected by clicking the associated `<label>`. This works any `<input>` field, by the way.

Comment: Another, easier, option would be using the [jQuery UI button widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio). It changes the label colors instead of using icons though.

Comment: @Satch3000: I posted a new answer, based on your update (and your JS Bin) example. It doesn't rely on CSS. If I were in your case, though, I'd use the solution that does use CSS (unless you're working with dynamic images) because of the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836120/990877), which uses CSS, let me offer an alternative solution.

Firstly; you want to keep track of which image goes with which radio button. Why not use an object literal?

```js
var checkedImages = {
    'radio1': "radio1_checked.png",
    'radio2': "radio2_checked.png"
};
var uncheckedImage = "unchecked.png";
```

This way you can easily refer to the different URL's like, e.g.: `checkedImages['radio2']`.

The change event handler would look very similar. The only difference is what you do with the `checkedLabels` and the `uncheckedLabels`:

```
var radios = $('input:radio');

radios.change(function() {
    var checkedLabels = radios.filter(':checked').parent();
    var uncheckedLabels = radios.filter(':not(:checked)').parent();

    uncheckedLabels.children('img').attr('src', uncheckedImage);

    checkedLabels.each(function() {
        var image = $(this).children('img');
        var name = $(this).attr('for');

        if (checkedImages[name] !== undefined) {
            // We have checked image for this radio button, so set it:
            image.attr('src', checkedImages[name]);
        } else {
            // We don't have checked image for this radio button.
            image.attr('src', uncheckedImage);
        }
    });
});
```

The main differences:

- We use [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to find the images.
- We use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to add more complicated logic for each of the unchecked label.
- We check the selected `<label>`s `for` attribute (using `.attr('for')`) to find out which image we should apply.

In this example only the `checked` state has different images for the different radio's. If you need different `unchecked` images as well, you can easily apply the same principle.

**Live example: http://jsbin.com/acalir/edit#javascript,html,live**

P.S. don't forget to set the `src` to the unchecked images (in HTML), or do the following (in JS):

```
$('input:radio').change();
```

This fires the `change` event programmatically, which will cause the unchecked images to be applied.

Answer (score 3):

You could use CSS to define which images goes with which radio button. Building on the JSBin example from [my answer to you previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835300/990877), you can use JavaScript to add a classname (e.g. `'checked'`) to the *parent* of the checked radio (i.e. the `<label>`):

```js
var radios = $('input:radio');

radios.change(function() {
    radios.filter(':checked').parent().addClass('checked');
    radios.filter(':not(:checked)').parent().removeClass('checked');
});
```

So, now that the `<label>` will have the `'checked'` class if that radio is selected, you can use CSS to style it:

```css
label {
    /* regular styles */
}
label[for="radio1"].checked {
    /* checked styles for #radio1's label */
}
label[for="radio2"].checked {
    /* checked styles for #radio2's label */
}
```

Using CSS instead of `<img>` tags does mean you will need to use `background-image`, so be aware of that.

**Live example: http://jsbin.com/ebapov/edit#javascript,html,live**

---

Just in case, here is a more verbose version of the JavaScript posted above:

```js
// Fetch the radio buttons (this is a jQuery collection):
var radios = $('input:radio');

radios.change(function() {

    // Filter the radio inputs into 'checked' and 'unchecked':
    var checkedInputs = radios.filter(':checked');
    var uncheckedInputs = radios.filter(':not(:checked)');

    // Get the 'checked' and 'unchecked' labels:
    var checkedLabels = checkedInputs.parent();
    var uncheckedLabels = uncheckedInputs.parent();

    // Add the class "checked" to the checked labels:
    checkedLabels.addClass('checked');

    // ... and remove it from the unchecked labels:
    uncheckedLabels.removeClass('checked');
});
```

Most of this code relies on the fact that jQuery functions can be **chained**. This means that when you call the [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function on a jQuery collection, it will actually return a collection containing the parent of *each* of the elements in the original collection. If you then call [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) on that new collection, it will add a classname to *each* of those parents.

Most of jQuery's functions can be chained.